# How do I not get OSError: [Errno -9993] Illegal combination of I/O devices when using pyaudio

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, ubuntu-18.04, pyaudio

I believe it's this module that's crashing my program and throwing this error:  OSError: [Errno -9993] Illegal combination of I/O devices.  I wrapped the call to this module in a try except SystemExit block, and it still crashed.  Any ideas how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 in a Conda virtual environment using Python 3.6.10.

```
###############################################################################################
######## STT SPEECH TO TEXT FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE VARIABLE: command
import pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

def myCommand():
    # "listens for commands"
    # We imported vosk up above.
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
    stream.start_stream()
    model = Model("model-en")
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
    while True:
        data = stream.read(2000)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        #print(rec.Result())
        # I commented out this line and added the 3 lines below
            myResult = rec.Result()
            myList = myResult.split("text")
            command = myList[1]
            return command
######## END STT SPEECH TO TEXT FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE VARIABLE: command
###############################################################################################
```

❯ pip list
Package           Version

---

beautifulsoup4    4.9.0
certifi           2020.4.5.1
chardet           3.0.4
click             7.1.1
future            0.18.2
gTTS              2.1.1
gTTS-token        1.1.3
idna              2.9
isort             4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3
mccabe            0.6.1
mock              4.0.1
MouseInfo         0.1.3
mypy              0.770
mypy-extensions   0.4.3
numpy             1.18.1
Pillow            7.1.1
pip               20.0.2
psutil            5.7.0
PyAudio           0.2.11
PyAutoGUI         0.9.50
PyGetWindow       0.0.8
pylint            2.4.4
PyMsgBox          1.0.7
pyperclip         1.8.0
PyQt5             5.14.2
PyQt5-sip         12.7.2
PyRect            0.1.4
PyScreeze         0.1.26
python3-xlib      0.15
PyTweening        1.0.3
requests          2.23.0
setuptools        45.2.0
six               1.14.0
soupsieve         2.0
subprocess.run    0.0.8
typed-ast         1.4.1
typing-extensions 3.7.4.1
urllib3           1.25.9
vosk              0.3.3
wheel             0.34.2
wikipedia         1.4.0
wrapt             1.11.2

#

I'm also running this module, and I'm not 100% sure which is causing the problem, although I suspect the first:

```
###############################################################################################
######## TTS TEXT TO SPEECH FUNCTION 

# This gets used all over to speak text aloud.
# It also prints to the console for people with bad memories.

from gtts import gTTS
import os

def talkToMe(mytext):
    # "speaks audio passed as argument"
    print(mytext)
    # can handle multiline text.
    #for line in mytext.splitlines():
        # uses the google text to speech module to synthesize text
    text_to_speech = gTTS(text=mytext, lang='en-uk')
        # saves syntesized speech to audio.mp3
        # this file gets written, played. and overwritten
        # over and over again.
    text_to_speech.save('audio.mp3')
        # the sox modules wrapper is mpg123.
        # This is called by the operating system imported os module.
    os.system('mpg123 -q audio.mp3')
###############################################################################################
######## END TTS TEXT TO SPEECH FUNCTION
```

#

```
Here's what I'm seeing as error:
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:ComputeDerivedVars():ivector-extractor.cc:183) Computing derived variables for iVector extractor
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:ComputeDerivedVars():ivector-extractor.cc:204) Done.
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:RemoveOrphanNodes():nnet-nnet.cc:948) Removed 1 orphan nodes.
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:RemoveOrphanComponents():nnet-nnet.cc:847) Removing 2 orphan components.
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:Collapse():nnet-utils.cc:1472) Added 1 components, removed 2
LOG (vosk[5.5.641~1-79319]:CompileLooped():nnet-compile-looped.cc:345) Spent 0.028789 seconds in looped compilation.
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated

Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1735
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1902
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi, inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2166
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2835
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Juliet.py", line 376, in <module>
    main()
  File "Juliet.py", line 366, in main
    output = mycommand.myCommand()[3:]
  File "/home/bard/Code/Juliet/SpeakAndHear/mycommand.py", line 10, in myCommand
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
  File "/home/bard/miniconda3/envs/Juliet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bard/miniconda3/envs/Juliet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9993] Illegal combination of I/O devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.  I needed to close my stream and terminate the process:

```
###############################################################################################
######## STT SPEECH TO TEXT FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE VARIABLE: command
import pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

def myCommand():
    # "listens for commands"
    # We imported vosk up above.
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
    stream.start_stream()
    model = Model("model-en")
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
    while True:
        data = stream.read(2000)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        #print(rec.Result())
        # I commented out this line and added the 3 lines below
            myResult = rec.Result()
            myList = myResult.split("text")
            command = myList[1]
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            p.terminate()
            return command
######## END STT SPEECH TO TEXT FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE VARIABLE: command
###############################################################################################
```